# Why is this so slow to load? Is there any technique to make this faster?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using the gem called "Mailboxer" ( https://github.com/ging/mailboxer )
This enables messaging system within Rails app.

With this gem, I'm showing 10 received messages for each page.
I'm using Kaminari for pagination here.

But, it is kinda too slow with my codes. 
It's issuing more than 25 sql at once :(
How can I make this faster?  It takes more than 1500ms to show just 1 page.

Here are my codes
What's wrong with this? Is there any technique to make this faster?

**controller**

```
@number_of_messages_to_display = 10
@messages = current_user.mailbox.inbox.page(params[:page]).per(@number_of_messages_to_display)
@messages_count = current_user.mailbox.inbox.count
```

**view(messages/index.html.erb)**

```
<%= @messages_count.to_s %> messages in your received message box.

<table>
    <% @messages.each do |m| %>
        <tr>
            <td><%= check_box_tag "id[]",m.id %></td>
            <td><%= if m.is_read?(current_user) then "Read" else "Un-read" %></td>
            <td><%= profile_link(m.recipients.first) if m.recipients.first != current_user %></td>
            <td><%= link_to m.subject, show_messages_path(:id => m) %></td>
            <td><%= today_datetime(m.last_message.created_at) %></td>
        </tr>
    <% end %>
</table>
```

**view(helpers/application_helper.rb)**

```
def profile_link(user)
    if user
        nickname = user.user_profile.try(:nickname) 
        username = user.try(:username)
        link_to nickname,  show_user_path(username)
    else
        "Un-known"
    end
end

def today_datetime(date_time)
  date_time.to_date == Date.current.to_date ? "<span class='text-info'>#{date_time.to_s(:us)}</span>".html_safe : date_time.to_s(:us)
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
get 'messages/:id' => 'messages#show', :as => :show_messages
get "users/:id" => 'users#show', :as => :show_user
```

**models/user.rb**

```
def to_param
  "#{username}"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Classic example of the [N + 1 problem.](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations)

You retrieve `@messages = current_user.mailbox.inbox.page`, which will retrieve records from the `messages` table.

In the view, you loop through them and check each message's `recipients` list (<strike>a `has_many` relationship, probably</strike> based on the `receipts` table, as can be seen [here](https://github.com/ging/mailboxer/blob/master/app/models/notification.rb)).  So, for each message, you end up sending another query to the database.

You can correct this by retrieving the recipients together with the messages (and the `last_message` association as well, since you're using it):

```
@messages = current_user.mailbox.inbox.
    includes(:receipt, :last_message).page
```

Also, you may have a different problem compounding this, as 25 queries should execute pretty quickly on a modern computer.  I'd recommend using something like the RailsPanel tool to track down where the time is being spent.

Comment: Thanks I tried to replace my code with yours. but now it says this error `ActionView::Template::Error (Association named 'recipients' was not found; perhaps you misspelled it?):`

Comment: You can look at the source of the gem, including the ActiveRecord models, on [github](https://github.com/ging/mailboxer/tree/master/app/models) . In this case, `recipients` is an attribute and is based on the `has_many :receipts` relationship inherited from the `Notification` model.

Comment: Thanks. Could you figure out why your code didn't work fine? Do you know the gem called "bullet"? I tried that with this page. But no alert pops up:(

Comment: I use the gem "rack-mini-profiler" to track and see how long it takes for every transaction.

Comment: @MKK, did you find any solution to this issue?  eager loading :receipts does not seem to make any difference on my side either

Comment: @MarkKenny I couldn't find any.